# Display text on link mouse over event

Tags: html, css, text, hover, mouseevent

i'm working on this element http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

what i need now is an "hover effect" when you go with the mouse over the different "Hours". I need to display a text in a fixed position. How can i do it? Here you can see a screenshot and the HTML/CSS

HTML

```
<div class="component">

            <!-- Start Nav Structure -->
            <button class="cn-button" id="cn-button"></button>
            <div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="primo"><span>07.45 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="secondo"><span>07.55 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="terzo"><span>08.15 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="quarto"><span>08.17 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="quinti"><span>10.47 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sesto"><span>13.20 Uhr</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="settimo"><span>16.30 Uhr</span></a></li>
                 </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- End of Nav Structure -->

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.component {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 2em;
height: 15em;
font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
transform: scale(1.1) !important;
margin-top: 90px; }
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT (CSS)

```
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -1.3em;
margin-left: -10em;
width: 10em;
height: 10em;
font-size: 1.5em;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
-webkit-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
pointer-events: none;}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
position: absolute;
right: -7.25em;
bottom: -7.25em;
display: block;
width: 14.5em;
height: 14.5em;
border-radius: 50%;
background: #000;
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #000 35%);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #000 35%);
background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #000 35%);
color: #f9d70a;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 2;
-webkit-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
-moz-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
-ms-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
pointer-events: auto; }

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #f9d70a 35%);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #f9d70a 35%);
background: radial-gradient(transparent 35%, #f9d70a 35%);
color: #000; }

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
position: fixed; /* fix the displacement bug in webkit browsers when     using tab key */
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li {
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease .3s;
transition: all .3s ease .3s;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:first-child {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-20deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-20deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(-20deg) skew(60deg);
}

 .csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(2) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(12deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(12deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(12deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(12deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav  li:nth-child(3) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(44deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(44deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(44deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(44deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(108deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(108deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(108deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(108deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(6) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(140deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(140deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(140deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(140deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav li:nth-child(7) {
-webkit-transform: rotate(172deg) skew(60deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(172deg) skew(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(172deg) skew(60deg);
transform: rotate(172deg) skew(60deg);
}

  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10em auto;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  }

 .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper ul {
  display: inline-block;
  }

 .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
 float: left;
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 5em;
 }

  ## Heading ## .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     color: inherit;
     text-decoration: none;
     }

 .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
 .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
 .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a{
background-color: #6F325C;
color: #fff;
}

  .no-csstransforms .cn-button {
   display: none;
  }
```

Comment: use `tooltip` of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You will need jQuery to insert the data-attr into a div below your list.

You'll need to fit this with your own element, but with position absolute you're able to position it where you want to.

Change the `data-tip=""` text to the desired text output.

```js
$('li span').hover(function() {
  var $tip = $(this).data('tip');
  $('#showtip').toggleClass('show').text($tip);
});
```

```css
#showtip {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#showtip.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="primo"><span data-tip="display1">07.45 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="secondo"><span data-tip="display2">07.55 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="terzo"><span data-tip="display3">08.15 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="quarto"><span data-tip="display4">08.17 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="quinti"><span data-tip="display5">10.47 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="sesto"><span data-tip="display6">13.20 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="settimo"><span data-tip="display7">16.30 Uhr</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="showtip"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i've tried but i can place the dta-tip under the buttun. I've edited the first post, now you can see the issue.

Comment: so your li's are relative positioned? It's best when adding a question to include all the CSS used for the example, removing the chance of errors. Currently without seeing your css I'm unable to do anything but guess for you.

Comment: i know sorry.. I've edited the first post... now you can see the li's CSS

Comment: any ideas? :) i've added more informations about the li CSS

Comment: Hey @NOW_Antonio Ive updated my answer for you... you'll have to include a div to show the tip and use jquery to insert the data.